# CoreLocation startMonitoringRegion not firing didenterregion /didexitregion delegates

Tags: iphone, core-location

i cant seem to get any of the didenterregion/didexitregion delegates firing , been stuck for 2 days on it

im using xcode4.2 with ios5 sdk and location simulation,

has anyone any luck getting this to work? is a 100m radius too small?(ive tried 1000 doesnt work too) or is there something wrong with my code

checked also with normal location updating and user location indeed enters region. could not find an answer anywhere as well

MainViewController(also CLLocationManagerDelegate)'s ViewDidLoad method:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
mapView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
MKCoordinateRegion region;// = {{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates =CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(1.34537, 103.84515);
    region.span = span;
region.center = coordinates;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];

if (locationManager==nil){
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
self.locationManager.delegate =self;    

if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]){
    NSLog(@"regionMonitoring available");

CLRegion* region3 = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coordinates radius:100 identifier:@"region3"];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region3 desiredAccuracy:1.0];    
NSLog(@"region = %@",region3);
NSLog(@"loc max = %f",self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance);
NSLog(@"location manger monitored regions = %@",self.locationManager.monitoredRegions);
```

also implemented all delegate methods neccessary

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didfailwitherror");
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.10f, longitude %+.10f\n",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
 }
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"didenterregion");

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"didexitregion");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{NSLog(@"monitoringDidFailForRegion");}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: I'm working with this too and having bad luck. I haven't tried this yet, but might it be that didEnterRegion is only called when you start from OUTSIDE the region, and then enter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How have you been testing the location? The regions are a little tricky, but once they are set up, they usually work great. What I usually do to test the region is just use the custom location in the Simulator. Use the same coordinates you are adding your region. 1000M is pretty large. I've tested with regions as small as 15-20M. If you have the right coordinates, it should be fine. Try switching back and forth from Apple HQ and your custom coordinates. You should be able to see the didEnter and didExit methods trip almost instantly if you have them logged out.

The one area you may have issues with is that the callbacks might not be getting to your method. None of my regions worked until I set up my AppDelegate as the CLLocationManagerDelegate. The app delegate finally got the updates and processed them correctly. I would try adding these callbacks there first, then work your way back to your mainviewcontroller. Hope this helps.

*UPDATE*

Since answering this question, I have learned a few things more about region monitoring. Regions get added with a minimum region size despite what you add for default. I was told by an Apple engineer that the minimum region size is 100M. I still feel they are very accurate, but it might help to understand why it will check you in. If you need precision better than 100M, you may need to look at other options.

Comment: I was having the same issue and the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods aren't firing. Any clues? I have set a region with radius 1000.

Comment: The iOS Simulator for 5.1 has a bug in it that doesn't allow region monitoring events to fire. There is an outstanding radar for it. You can download the iOS 5 simulator or the iOS 6 simulator if you have access and should allow the region monitoring events to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @BillBurgess for the fantastic answer.  Just to make things clear, are you saying that you implemented didEnterRegion and the others in the AppDelegate?  Wow.  I thought a delegate was a delegate... I'm having the same trouble - I'll try moving the function calls.

Comment: I initially implemented the delegates in the AppDel just to make things easier, but have since moved them off to a custom class that handles all the location delegate methods. So no, you don't have to implement them in the AppDel if you don't want. It just worked better for me when starting out until I fully understood what was going on.

Comment: Thanks again @BillBurgess.  Although it makes more sense that anything can be the delegate, I was hoping it would solve my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360386/didenterregion-works-in-foreground-but-not-background).